# Select multiple columns in IF clause conditionally?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to select different fields inside a `SELECT` conditionally?

Pseudocode:

```
CREATE VIE myview AS SELECT
  id,
  IF(signal_field == 1)
     firstname as first,
     lastname as last
  ELSE
     concat(firstname + lastname) as firstlast
  FROM mytable;
```

Comment: you can select different fields but you can't select different number of fields, you can use stored procedure with dynamic sql code of run different selects based on input conditions

Comment: The output recordset structure in a view must be static (definite, deterministic). The number of fields and their types cannot be altered.

Comment: @Akina, yes, there is a mistype in my comment - "dynamic sql code OR run different selects" .. based on flow control :) I propose to use one of these solutions. Dynamic SQL may be easier if you have many parameters.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  id,(CASE WHEN signal_field =1 THEN firstname END) as first,
     (CASE WHEN signal_field =1 THEN lastname  END) lastname as last,
     (CASE WHEN signal_field!=1 THEN concat(firstname,lastname) END) as firstlast
FROM mytable;
```